# Recycle content in bad edit attempts?

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits, edit-history

Once someone mistakenly tried to edit someone elses answer with a correction to their own question / answer. Is the content of the attempted edit then lost to them if rejected or can they recycle it somehow and use it in editing the correct post afterwards?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Links to the review-summaries of the edits a user suggested are recorded on the user's page; these include a record of the proposed edit.

[The list of suggested edits](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) is the "suggestion" tab on the "all actions" tab.

Comment: Ok so they will be available if you know the reviewer of the edit, but the one making the proposal usually won't know who that was, or will they?

Comment: Ok, great then I suppose this answers my question.

Comment: @mathreadler The link posted by quid shows all suggestions made by you. Every user can see the suggestions made by them, in their profile, just as you see yours. (And all other users can see them too).

Comment: @mathreadler I clarified the post to make it more clear that what I meant  is on the page of the user that proposed the edit. (But in principle it is also on the page of the reviewer, yet under "reviews" instead of "suggestions")